# Filter List<string> based on only a Substring

Tags: c#, string, list, linq, filtering

I have a list of SKUs (product numbers) and need to sort it based on a very specific criteria.

A list of SKUs, for example:

```
List<string> skuList = new List<string>()
{
    "SKU001040AA",
    "SKU003010DED",
    "SKU002010VEVW",
    "SKU003040EEGE",
    "SKU001020GEF"
};
```

Each SKU is structured in a fashion as follows:

- The first three characters are filler
- The 4th-6th characters refer to the group the SKU belongs to
- The 7th-9th characters refer to the priority a SKU has within its respective group
- The remaining 10th and so on characters are filler

As such, the first SKU in the list belongs to group 001 and has a priority of 040. A lower numeric value has a higher priority. In which case, 030 is higher priority than 040. My goal here is to filter the list so that only the highest priority SKUs within their respective groups are kept. Using the above list for reference, a filtered list would contain "SKU003010DED", "SKU002010VEVW" and "SKU001020GEF". The filtered list does not need to be ordered. It will ultimately be packed into a JSON object and be sent away.

I have tried a few different approaches, several of which seemed to be very inefficient. It occurred to me that I could use the present format of the SKUs to order the list easily. After that, I thought it would be possible to use the Contains() method to check if a substring existed, but naturally that only works for complete strings within the list...

```
skuList = skuList.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
List<string> skuListFiltered = new List<string>();
foreach (var sku in skuList)
{
    //Unsure of the best approach to view substrings of skuList
    if (!skuList.Contains(sku.Substring(3,3)))
    {
        skuListFiltered.Add(sku);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to filter this list in such a fashion, or should I try an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processing should go as follows:

- Identify SKU groups in the list
- Attach each SKU to its respective group
- Order SKUs within each group by priority
- Pick the top item in each group
- Make a flat list from grouped result

Here is how you do it with LINQ:

```
var topPriority = skuList
    .GroupBy(sku => sku.Substring(3, 3))
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(sku => sku.Substring(6, 3)).First())
    .ToList();
```

Note that since priorities are zero-padded, they have the same length of 3 characters. Hence, lexicographical ordering is the same as numerical ordering.

Comment: Shouldn't the order be ascending? Otherwise +1, got the exact same resulting code myself.

Comment: @Lucas Right, OP says "lower number --> higher priority". Thanks!

Comment: That is incredibly simple and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for elaborating on each step. It helps me understand the LINQ (which I really need to learn better anyway).

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you make a class like this one. The key here are the implicit cast operators; an instance of this class can be assigned to or from a string, but you can also use its properties to parse it.

```
class Sku
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string Group  { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", Prefix, Group, Priority, Suffix);
    }

    static public implicit operator Sku(string input)
    {
        return new Sku
        {
            Prefix = input.Substring(0,3),
            Group = input.Substring(3,3),
            Priority = input.Substring(6,3),
            Suffix = input.Substring(9)
        };
    }

    static public implicit operator string(Sku input)
    {
        return input.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now the LINQ is trivial:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        List<Sku> skuList = new List<Sku>()  //Notice this is strongly typed as <Sku> now
        {
            "SKU001040AA",
            "SKU003010DED",
            "SKU002010VEVW",
            "SKU003040EEGE",
            "SKU001020GEF"
        };

        var results = skuList
            .Select( s => s.Group )
            .Distinct()
            .Select
            ( 
                g => skuList.Where
                ( 
                    s => s.Group == g
                )
                .OrderBy
                (
                    s => s.Priority
                )
                .First()
            );

        foreach (var r in results)
            Console.WriteLine(r);                                                                        

    }   
}
```

Output:

```
SKU001020GEF
SKU003010DED
SKU002010VEVW
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FObFiA)

Comment: I like this. Just a question, what's the best way to handle a string in the wrong format in the implicit cast operator code. Substring can throw exceptions if the string is too short. What's the best way to feed that back out, just letting it throw the argument out of range exception feels a bit weird. Is it.just a case of checking string length/catching the exception and throwing an InvalidCastException?

Comment: If invalid SKUs are expected and common, you can still allow the cast but return an empty SKU object, perhaps with an IsValid property set to false, so you can check it in code. If invalid SKUs are rare and exceptional, raise an exception. Another option is allow the cast to return null; the caller will need to do a null check before doing anything else.